# How do you get the image out of LPMetadataProvider on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, ios13

I want to use `LPMetadataProvider` (new on iOS 13) to get an image representation for a link (for instance the header image for a news article link).

```swift
let provider = LPMetadataProvider()
provider.startFetchingMetadata(for: URL(string: "https://someurl/")!) { (metadata, error) in
    metadata?.imageProvider?.howDoIGetTheImageOut()
})
```

Seemingly you can do `loadDataRepresentation`, but iOS 13 docs seem to indicate more of a recommendation to use `loadPreviewImage`, but I'm not sure what to pass or how to use that method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61286308/1835803

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let metadataProvider = LPMetadataProvider()
let url = URL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/p/B1ZLpsZnwkY/")!

metadataProvider.startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { metadata, error in
  if error != nil {
    return
  }

  let IMAGE_TYPE = kUTTypeImage as String
  metadata?.imageProvider?.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: IMAGE_TYPE, completionHandler: { (url, imageProviderError) in
            if imageProviderError != nil {
                // The fetch failed; handle the error.
                return
            }
            let myImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: (url?.path)!)
        })

   }
```