# Can we extract image from LPLinkView in LinkPresentation framework?

Tags: swift, xcode, web-crawler, api-linkpreview

I want to present a rich link in my app and also send those data to my server.
I need to access the image inside the view of [LPLinkView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/linkpresentation/lplinkview).

how can I access the parameters inside it? (like: image, description, title, icon, and ext...)

[image: LPLinkView of URL swift]

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, you can't access any internal properties of an `LPLinkView`, but you can easily create your own view. The `LPLinkMetadata` object has everything you need, you just need to know how to extract the images from its `iconProvider` and `imageProvider`, which are subclasses of `NSItemProvider`.

### UIKit (iOS)

You can use `NSItemProvdier`'s `loadObject(ofClass:)` method to easily get a `UIImage`. This works because `UIImage` conforms to the `NSItemProviderReading` protocol.

```swift
import LinkPresentation
import UIKit

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/q/61286308/2101447")!

LPMetadataProvider().startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { (linkMetadata, error) in
    guard let linkMetadata = linkMetadata, let imageProvider = linkMetadata.iconProvider else { return }

    print(linkMetadata.title ?? "Untitled")

    imageProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (image, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            // handle error
            return
        }

        if let image = image as? UIImage {
            // do something with image
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                imageView.image = image
            }
        } else {
            print("no image available")
        }
    }
}
```

### SwiftUI

SwiftUI's `Image` is a `struct`, so it cannot conform to `NSItemProviderReading`. It's easiest to use the UIKit code above to obtain a `UIImage` and instantiate a SwiftUI `Image` from that.

```swift
...

if let uiImage = loadedImage as? UIImage {
    let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
}
```

### AppKit (macOS)

Unlike its `UIImage` sister, `NSImage` does not conform to `NSItemProviderReading`, which means you'll have to use `NSItemProvdier`'s older `loadItem(forTypeIdentifier:options:)` method.

You'll need to specify the `typeIdentifier` and initialize the `NSImage` from `Data` yourself, but otherwise it's pretty much the same.

```swift
import CoreServices // may be necessary for kUTTypeImage 
import LinkPresentation
import AppKit

let imageView = NSImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/q/61286308/2101447")!

LPMetadataProvider().startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { (linkMetadata, error) in
    guard let linkMetadata = linkMetadata, let imageProvider = linkMetadata.iconProvider else { return }

    print(linkMetadata.title ?? "Untitled")

    imageProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil) { (data, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            // handle error
            return
        }
        guard let data = data as? Data else {
            print("no image available")
            return
        }
        if let image = NSImage(data: data) {
            // do something with image
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageView.image = image
            }
        } else {
            print("no image available")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to put `self.` before `imageView` in `DispatchQueue` closure